# Kapt dependency issue

Tags: android, android-room, dagger, kapt, android-moxy

I have project that was initially started with Java(contains dagger and moxy frameworks).

I have added room dependency and I have create all room components in kotlin so as dependency I using:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"

kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
```

When I adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` I have dagger error:

> cannot find symbol DaggerAppComponent;

When I try to add `kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"` the error disappear but I got new error, the moxy(MVP framework)`@InjectPresenter` not working in runtime(presenters is null)

moxy initial dependencies

```
implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy:2.2.1"
implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-app-compat:2.2.1"
annotationProcessor "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-compiler:2.2.1"
```

dagger initial dependencies

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
testImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
```

Why when I adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` dagger stops compile?

Answer (score 1):

Hi maybe you have a incompatibility problem with dependencies. I'm using room with this dependencies:

```
//ROOM dependencies
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0-rc01"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0-rc01"
```

**Important:**: Make sure that you have declare the android plugins properly, Is important the order plugin declaration, I've imported like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

PD: I'm using `dagger-hilt` and `room` in the same project and i'm not problems.